# Make multiple httpServletRequest from java code

Tags: servlets

I am very new to Java. There is a Model Server web service, now to test it we require to create a testing framework. For testing I have to provide multiple test inputs from a file. and for each input I have to run the web service. Now I want to know that is there any way to create HttpServletRequest from java code, as I have to create a new Http post request for each test input. Please suggest me if there is any alternate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the builtin [`java.net.URLConnection`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests) or the more convenient [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/).